# Getting Warning when trying to put two "add_filter" codes together not sure what it means

Tags: php

> Warning: array_unshift() [function.array-unshift]: The first argument
>   should be an array in
>   /public_html/blank.com/main/wp-content/themes/gbs-prime-child-theme-master/functions-parent-override.php
>   on line 61

```
<?php

add_filter( 'gb_deal_submission_fields', 'new_filter_deal_submission_fields', 10, 1 );
add_action( 'submit_deal', 'save_new_fields', 10, 1 );
function new_filter_deal_submission_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['deal_embed'] = array(
        'weight' => 73,
        'label' => 'Featured Content',
        'type' => 'textarea',
        'required' => FALSE,
        'description' => 'Replace">http://blank.com/main/add-youtube-or-vimeo-video/">Replace Project Image with your own youtube or Vimeo video'
    );
    return $fields;
}


function set_featured_content( $post_id, $featured_content ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_featured_content', $featured_content );
    return $featured_content;
}  
add_filter( 'gb_featured_content', 'add_iframe' );
function add_iframe( $content ) {
    return $content ;
    return '' . $content . '';
}   

add_filter( 'gb_deal_submission_fields', 'deal_submission_categories', 10, 1 ); 
add_action( 'submit_deal', 'save_new_fields', 10, 1 ); 
function deal_submission_categories( $fields ) { 
   $fields['deal_cat'] = array( 
       'weight' => 3, 
       'label' => 'Campaign Category:', 
       'type' => 'input', 
       'required' => FALSE, 
       'description' => 'Select your Campaign category' 
   ); 
   $fields['deal_tag'] = array( 
       'weight' => 3, 
       'label' => 'Campaign Tag:', 
       'type' => 'input', 
       'required' => FALSE, 
       'description' => 'Select your Tag' 
   ); 
   //locations 
   $args=array( 
       'orderby' => 'name', 
       'hide_empty'=> 0, 
       'parent' => 0, 
       'order' => 'ASC', 
       'taxonomy' => 'gb_location' 
   ); 
   $gb_locs = array(); 
   $locations=get_categories($args); 
   foreach($locations as $location){ 
       $gb_locs[$location->name] = $location->name; 
   } 
   array_unshift($gb_cats, "Choose a category"); 
   $fields['deal_loc'] = array( 
       'weight' => 3, 
       'label' => 'Campaign Location:', 
       'type' => 'select', 
       'required' => FALSE, 
       'options' => $gb_locs, 
       'description' => 'Select your Location' 
   ); 
   return $fields; 
} 
function save_new_fields( Group_Buying_Deal $deal ) { 

$featured_content = isset( $_POST['gb_deal_deal_embed'] ) ? $_POST['gb_deal_deal_embed'] : '';
    $post_id = $deal->get_id();
    set_featured_content( $post_id, $featured_content );
   $project_cat = isset( $_POST['gb_deal_deal_cat'] ) ? $_POST['gb_deal_deal_cat'] : ''; 
   $project_tag = isset( $_POST['gb_deal_deal_tag'] ) ? $_POST['gb_deal_deal_tag'] : ''; 
   $project_loc = isset( $_POST['gb_deal_deal_loc'] ) ? $_POST['gb_deal_deal_loc'] : ''; 
   $post_id = $deal->get_id(); 
   $cat = get_term_by( 'name', $project_cat, 'gb_category' ); 
   $tag = get_term_by( 'name', $project_tag, 'gb_tag' ); 
   $loc = get_term_by( 'name', $project_loc, 'gb_location' ); 
   wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $cat->term_id, 'gb_category' ); 
   wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $tag->term_id, 'gb_tag' ); 
   wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $loc->term_id, 'gb_location' ); 
}
```

Comment: The error message is quite clear - is `$gb_cats` ever defined?

Comment: @ kingkero : would this be correct? $gb_cats = array();
   $categories=get_categories($args);
   foreach($categories as $category){
       $gb_cats[$category->name] = $category->name;
   }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$gb_cats` is out of scope to the function `deal_submission_categories`. You can bring it into scope using `global` keyword.

```
$gb_cats = ();
function deal_submission_categories($fields) {
global $gb_cats;
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked!
$gb_cats = array(); $categories=get_categories($args); foreach($categories as $category){ $gb_cats[$category->name] = $category->name; }